# Record and send/stream sound from iOS device to a server continuously

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, audio-recording

I am developing an iOS app that has a button with a microphone on it (along with other features). When the user presses the microphone, it gets highlighted and the app should now start recording sound from the device´s microphone and send to a server (a server dedicated to the app, developed by people that I know, so I can affect its design).

I am looking for the simplest yet sturdiest approach to do this, i.e. I have no need to develop a complicated streaming solution or VoIP functionality, unless it is as simple to do as anything else.

The main problem is that we have no idea for how long the user will be recording sound, but we want to make sure that sounds are sent to the server continuously, we do not wish to wait until the user has finished recording. It is okay if the data arrives to the server in chunks however we do not wish to miss any information that the user may be recording, so one chunk must continue where the previous one ended and so on.

Our first thought was to create "chunks" of sound clips of for example 10 seconds and send them continuously to the server. Is there any streaming solution that is better/simpler that I am missing out on?

My question is, what would be the most simple but still reliable approach on solving this task on iOS?

Is there a way to extract chunks of sound from a running recording by AVAudioRecorder, without actually stopping the recording?

Comment: Anyone who can suggest just some implementation info (like a short code example or just example of classes to use) on how to record and then send data?

Comment: I have to make a similar app. i have to send data while recording. Did you found any solution for that?

Comment: Hi jake, have you been able to resolve your question? I'm also looking for the same functionality.

Comment: I used the solution accepted below, but the result was not great because there were parts missing in the "gaps" between recordings. Unfortunately, we never finished the project after that, so it is up to you to keep working on it and if you find something I'm sure it would be very appreciated if you post it here :)

Comment: Could you please share your source code, It will save my effort and will focus only on the existing issue.

Comment: It is not possible - sorry

Answer (score 20, accepted):

look at [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29)
in this tutorial, the sound recorded will be saved at soundFileURL, then you will just have to create an nsdata with that content, and then send it to your server.
hope this helped.

EDIT : 
I just created a version that contain 3 buttons, REC, SEND and Stop :
REC : will start recording into a file.
SEND : will save what was recorded on that file in a NSData, and send it to a server, then will restart recording.
and STOP : will stop recording. 
here is the code : 
in your .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *recordButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *sendButton;

@property BOOL stoped;

- (IBAction)startRec:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sendToServer:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;
@end
```

and in the .m file :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize audioRecorder;
@synthesize recordButton,sendButton,stopButton;
@synthesize stoped;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
sendButton.enabled = NO;
stopButton.enabled = NO;
stoped = YES;

NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tempsound.caf"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error = nil;

audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                 initWithURL:soundFileURL
                 settings:recordSettings
                 error:&error];
audioRecorder.delegate = self;
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

} else {
    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
}
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (BOOL) sendAudioToServer :(NSData *)data {
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithData:data];
    //now you'll just have to send that NSData to your server

    return YES;
}
-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
NSLog(@"stoped");
    if (!stoped) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url];
        [self sendAudioToServer:data];
        [recorder record];
NSLog(@"stoped sent and restarted");
    }
}
- (IBAction)startRec:(id)sender {
if (!audioRecorder.recording)
{
    sendButton.enabled = YES;
    stopButton.enabled = YES;
    [audioRecorder record];
}
}

- (IBAction)sendToServer:(id)sender {
stoped = NO;
[audioRecorder stop];
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
stopButton.enabled = NO;
sendButton.enabled = NO;
recordButton.enabled = YES;

stoped = YES;
if (audioRecorder.recording)
{
    [audioRecorder stop];
}
}
@end
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you! This will be very helpful. The main problem I'm facing is on how to send sound while keeping the recording running. Any suggestions on that? Can I send the file to server while still recording it, or start recording on a new file without without any gaps (switching buffer as suggested by Joachim), so that I can send the old file to server?

Comment: according to https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html, you can specify the file location to record sound when you initializes the recorder, wich mean you'll have to either wait until the file is uploaded to the server, or to reinitialise your recorder with a new file location.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple recordings running simultaneously? So that I can start a new recording before stopping the old one, to make sure no information is missed?

Comment: well why not having multiple AVAudioRecorder intances

Comment: These kind of things don't always work simultaneously, I was hoping that if you had tried it you could verify that it works. I will try having two instances and swap between them.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi, I have about 22 hrs to award the bounty. I will award it to you if you update the answer according to this discussion and make it a bit more thorough. I think that a 50pts bounty answer should be detailed and contain some guidelines on the implementation only by reading it -  to help other people reading the question. In this state I will reward Joachim with the bounty as he got more votes (but your answer will likely still be the accepted one)

Comment: thats the solution i found, hope this helped

Comment: Thank you, lots of creds to you for your effort, the bonus is yours! I will accept your answer as soon as I have tried it out.

Comment: just forgot to tell you, put the processing for updating your audio to server (sendAudioToServer ) in a separated thread, so the recorder will restart immediately.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi, This is very helfull. My issue is resolved with this answer @Mehdi

Comment: @Mehdi,@jake_hetfield Could you share the source code for multiple AVAudioRecorder instances. I have to build the similar solutions.

Answer (score 20):

It might actually be easier to have fixed-size chunks, instead of fixed-time. Then you can have two buffers, one that you currently fill with sample data. When the active buffer is full, then switch to fill the other buffer, while sending a signal to a sender-thread that takes the first buffer and sends it to the server.

You can of course use fixed-time instead, but then you need to make sure that the buffer is large enough to keep all samples, or use a dynamic buffer that can increase in size when needed. The double-buffering and sending thread can still be the same though.

Comment: Good idea, I will definetely have a look at this!